# Proprietary C extension for Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, bundler

I've written some proprietary business logic in C that I want to run from Ruby. I attempted to write it as a gem that was simply included by Bundler from a path internal to the main project; however, Bundler "doesn't build native extensions in that case" (tmoore in the #bundler irc channel).

I would rather not create a separate private repository for this C extension gem. I would also rather not precompile native versions for all the environments. RubyInline does not appear to be an option because the C is more than just a couple functions, makes heavy use of pointers to structs passed between functions, etc.

Are there any options for building C into a project such that the C will be compiled on the target machine via standard bundle installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tmoore in the #bundler irc channel for pointing me to the following:

- http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH-path-
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1679#issuecomment-11162403

From the former:

> Unlike :git, bundler does not compile C extensions for gems specified
>   as paths.

And from the latter:

> I think I'm going to go with "please use git gems if you need to
>   compile extensions". :path, as an option, is a way to add directories
>   that you are managing manually to the load path. If you need an
>   extension built in those directories, you should be doing it yourself
>   as part of managing that directory manually. :)

So that's the official word. If you want Bundler to compile a proprietary extension, load your extension gem from a private Git repository. (This was helpful: https://gist.github.com/masonforest/4048732.) In order to avoid overly wide privileges, you can:

1. create a new Github account dedicated to your private repos
2. grant it read only access to only your private extension repos
3. create an oauth token for that dedicated Github user: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/
4. incorporate that oauthtoken into your git url in your gemfile:

   gem 'your_gem_name', git:
       'https://your_oauth_token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/account/project.git'